# How to switch between Class using addClass & removeClass?

Tags: jquery, css, switchers

I create my own Switcher jQuery, and I want to remove class when click on another color, for example : I have "blue" class on body tag and when someone click on red should remove the blue class and replace it with red class etc..

**Code :**

```
$("body").addClass("wide light blue");

// Switcher jQuery Plugin
$(".switcher-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#switcher").toggleClass("open");
});

// Theme Layout Switch
$(".layout").change(function() {
    var layout = $(".layout").val();
    $(".wrapper").css("width",layout);
});

// Theme Skins Switch
$(".skins").change(function() {
    var skin = $(".skins").val();
    $("body").toggleClass(skin);
});

// Theme Colors Switch
$(".colors span").each(function() {
     var data_color = $(this).attr("data-color");
     $(this).click(function() {
         $("body").toggleClass(data_color);
     });
});
```

**Demo :**
https://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/p18cqa5s/

Comment: You're not really using the `wide` and `light` classes for anything, so just removing all classes seems like it should work -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p18cqa5s/6/

Comment: Yes you're right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that the `each()` loop is redundant as you can access the `data-color` attribute directly within the click handler.

Secondly, to achieve what you require you can provide a space-delimited list of all the classes to be removed using `removeClass` before adding the new class with `addClass`. Try this:

```
$(".colors span").click(function() {
    $("body")
        .removeClass('blue red green orange carrot violet pink gold')
        .addClass($(this).data("color"));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p18cqa5s/2/)

However this may become a little difficult to maintain if colours are added or removed. A better pattern would be to call a single function to set the classes on the `body` element whenever an option is chosen or a colour is clicked. Try this:

```
$(".skins, .layout").change(applyClasses);
$(".colors span").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    applyClasses();
});

function applyClasses() {
    var classes = [
        $(".skins").val(),
        $(".layout").val(),
        $(".colors span.active").data('color')
    ];

    $('body').removeClass().addClass(classes.join(' '));
}

applyClasses(); // on load
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p18cqa5s/4/)

Comment: The first method is work fine for me, Thank you so much you save my project :) this is my new demo now : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/p18cqa5s/18/)

Comment: Glad to help. I would suggest you use the second method though, as it's far more extensible.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing set color from `body` element `className` using `.split()` , with parameter `" "` , `.slice()` with parameter `-1` to select last `className` set on `body` before calling `.toggleClass()` to set new color ; also adding `true` to `.toggleClass()` to prevent removing `class` if same color swatch clicked in succession

```
// Theme Colors Switch
$(".colors span").each(function() {
     var data_color = $(this).attr("data-color");
     $(this).click(function() {
         $("body").removeClass(document.body.className.split(" ").slice(-1)[0])
         .toggleClass(data_color, true);
     });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p18cqa5s/3/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

use the `removeClass()` method to remove the existing classes and call `addClass()` to add the new class.

```
// Theme Colors Switch
$(".colors span").each(function() {
     var data_color = $(this).attr("data-color");
     $(this).click(function() {
        $("body").removeClass().addClass(data_color);            
     });
});
```

`removeClass()` method without any parameters will remove all the classes.

More simplified version

```
$(".colors span").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-color"));
})
```

Make sure to put your code inside `document.ready` event

Comment: Note that the `body` will have classes added to it from the `change` events on the `select` elements. Using `removeClass` would eliminate those as well as the colour classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add all `data_color` to an array and then on click of color remove all class from the body which are in the array. After that add new class like following.

```
var data_color= [];
// Theme Colors Switch
$(".colors span").each(function() {
     data_color.push($(this).attr("data-color"));
     $(this).click(function() {
         $("body").removeClass(data_color.join(' ')).addClass($(this).attr("data-color"));
     });
});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p18cqa5s/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)